# Fitting a logistic regression using lassoglm in matlab

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

I am fitting a logistic regression model using lassoglm in matlab. I issued the following command

```
[B,FitInfo] = lassoglm(ec50,Y,'binomial','Lambda',0.0001,'CV',10);
```

Now once I get the coefficients B, how am I supposed to use it. I mean do I have to do

$P(y=1) = \frac{e^{(\theta^tx)}}{1 + e^{(\theta^tx)}}$ where $\theta$s are obtained from B. Is it the case?

Comment: B is essentially the weights. You can use ec50*B to get estimates for the fit of Y.

Comment: Other threads bearing on this problem can be found by [searching our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logistic+regression?sort=votes&pageSize=50).